# How can I route Observable values to different Subscribers?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

This is all just pseudo code...

Ok here is my scenario, I have an incoming data stream that gets parsed into packets.

I have an `IObservable<Packets> Packets`

Each packet has a Packet ID, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4

I want to create observables that only receive a specific ID.

so I do:

`Packets.Where(p=>p.Id == 1)`

for example... that gives me an `IObservable<Packets>` that only gives me packets of Id 1.

I may have several of these:

```
Packets.Where(p=>p.Id == 2)
Packets.Where(p=>p.Id == 3)
Packets.Where(p=>p.Id == 4)
Packets.Where(p=>p.Id == 5)
```

This essentially works, but the more Ids I want to select the more processing is required, i.e. the `p=>p.Id` will be run for every single Id, even after a destination Observable has been found.

How can I do the routing so that it is more efficient, something analogous:

Dictionary listeners;

listeners.GetValue(packet.Id).OnDataReceived(packet)

so that as soon as an id is picked up by one of my IObservables, then none of the others get to see it?

### Updates

Added an extension based on Lee Campbell's groupby suggestion:

```
public static class IObservableExtensions
{
    class RouteTable<TKey, TSource>
    {
        public static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<IObservable<TSource>, IObservable<IGroupedObservable<TKey, TSource>>> s_routes = new ConditionalWeakTable<IObservable<TSource>, IObservable<IGroupedObservable<TKey, TSource>>>();
    }

    public static IObservable<TSource> Route<TKey, TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector, TKey id)
    {
        var grouped = RouteTable<TKey, TSource>.s_routes.GetValue(source, s => s.GroupBy(p => selector(p)).Replay().RefCount());
        return grouped.Where(e => e.Key.Equals(id)).SelectMany(e => e);
    }
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
Subject<Packet> packetSubject = new Subject<Packet>();

        var packets = packetSubject.AsObservable();

        packets.Route((p) => p.Id, 5).Subscribe((p) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("5");
        });

        packets.Route((p) => p.Id, 4).Subscribe((p) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("4");
        });

        packets.Route((p) => p.Id, 3).Subscribe((p) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("3");
        });

        packetSubject.OnNext(new Packet() { Id = 1 });
        packetSubject.OnNext(new Packet() { Id = 2 });
        packetSubject.OnNext(new Packet() { Id = 3 });
        packetSubject.OnNext(new Packet() { Id = 4 });
        packetSubject.OnNext(new Packet() { Id = 5 });
        packetSubject.OnNext(new Packet() { Id = 4 });
        packetSubject.OnNext(new Packet() { Id = 3 });
```

output is:
3, 4, 5, 4, 3

It only checks the Id for every group when it sees a new packet id.

Comment: Why do you feel that this current approach means more processing is required? Is it significant? Also, what do you mean by "even after a destination Observable has been found"?

Comment: Thinking about this further the `.Where` operator is precisely correct for this use case. Unless the set up cost is enormous for each subscription to the observable then there isn't a better way. If the set up cost is enormous then you can use `.Publish()` to share the subscription, but you'd still then use `.Where(...)` to filter the values anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at `GroupBy` and then checking if there is a performance pay off. I assume there is, but is it significant?

```
Packets.GroupBy(p=>p.Id)
```

Example code with tests on how to use `GroupBy` as a type of router

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
var source = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(100, 1),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(200, 2),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(300, 3),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(400, 4),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(500, 5),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(600, 6),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(700, 7),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(800, 8),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(900, 9),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000, 10),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1100, 11)
    );

var router = source.GroupBy(i=>i%4)
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();

var zerosObserver = scheduler.CreateObserver<int>();
router.Where(grp=>grp.Key == 0)
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(grp=>grp)
    .Subscribe(zerosObserver);

var onesObserver = scheduler.CreateObserver<int>();
router.Where(grp => grp.Key == 1)
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp)
    .Subscribe(onesObserver);

var twosObserver = scheduler.CreateObserver<int>();
router.Where(grp => grp.Key == 2)
        .Take(1)
        .SelectMany(grp => grp)
        .Subscribe(twosObserver);

var threesObserver = scheduler.CreateObserver<int>();
router.Where(grp => grp.Key == 3)
        .Take(1)
        .SelectMany(grp => grp)
        .Subscribe(threesObserver);

scheduler.Start();

ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(new[] { ReactiveTest.OnNext(400, 4), ReactiveTest.OnNext(800, 8)}, zerosObserver.Messages);
ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(new[] { ReactiveTest.OnNext(100, 1), ReactiveTest.OnNext(500, 5), ReactiveTest.OnNext(900, 9)}, onesObserver.Messages);
ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(new[] { ReactiveTest.OnNext(200, 2), ReactiveTest.OnNext(600, 6), ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000, 10) }, twosObserver.Messages);
ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(new[] { ReactiveTest.OnNext(300, 3), ReactiveTest.OnNext(700, 7), ReactiveTest.OnNext(1100, 11)}, threesObserver.Messages);
```

Comment: I thought about `.GroupBy` too, but wouldn't the OP then need to subscribe to the inner observable only if the key were correct and thus is effectively a `.Where` anyway, but in this case it's building an unnecessary internal dictionary? The OP is filtering based on a key and I couldn't think of any way to avoid a `.Where`.

Comment: You still need a `Where` however this is only evaluated once per subscription. The GroupBy performs the branch once per value. Thus you have an O1 cost vs an On cost (where n isnumber of subscribers)

Comment: I think this is a question that is splitting hairs on performance. I would think that the only way to really know what is more performant is to time the various approaches.

Comment: Agreed, and as posted in my answer. However in trading application where we saw dozens to hundreds of messages per second on a client, it was defiantly wasteful to if check every message for every subscriber. That was just throwing cpu cycles on the floor.

Comment: I would love to see a comparison between the different alternatives. The answer I just posted trades CPU for memory so I think this will come down to a matter of opinion rather than any hard science.

Comment: I like this, and have tried to come up with an extension method which I will add to my question that is based on the groups.

Comment: @Enigmativity I will also evaluate your solution.

Comment: @LeeCampbell my extension method with groupby, everytime it sees a new packet id that hasn't been seen before, you get an On subscription where n is number of subscrbers.


Can it be improved so it doesn't try to create new groups, only subscription creates new groups?

Maybe my extension is working a little differently to how you suggested?

Comment: That sounds correct. For each new group a subscriber will be pushed a new group, they will evaluate the group key. To avoid doing iy more than once, use Take(1) after the where (as you know you only want and can only get one group)

Comment: If I do...

`public static IObservable<TSource> Route<TKey, TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector, TKey id)
        {
            var grouped = RouteTable<TKey, TSource>.s_routes.GetValue(source, s => s.GroupBy(p => selector(p)).Publish().RefCount());

            return grouped.Where(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Routing: {id.ToString()}");
                return e.Key.Equals(id);
            }).Take(1).SelectMany(e => e);
        }
`

I still get it checking e,Key.Equals id the first time it sees a new packet id

Comment: @LeeCampbell - I want to try and move the creation of groups to subscriber time? if that's possible?

Comment: I dont know of a way to move creation of groups to time of subscription. I am also just trying to think if this is something you actually want to do. I have updated the answer to show how i meant to use `GroupBy` (i.e. no need for a `RouteTable`)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an operator that I wrote quite some time ago, but I think it does what you're after. I still think that a simple `.Where` is probably better - even with multiple subscribers.

Nevertheless, I wanted a `.ToLookup` for observables that operates like the same operator for enumerables.

It isn't memory efficient, but it implements `IDisposable` so that it can be cleaned up afterwards. It also isn't thread-safe so a little hardening might be required.

Here it is:

```
public static class ObservableEx
{
    public static IObservableLookup<K, V> ToLookup<T, K, V>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, K> keySelector, Func<T, V> valueSelector, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return new ObservableLookup<T, K, V>(source, keySelector, valueSelector, scheduler);
    }

    internal class ObservableLookup<T, K, V> : IDisposable, IObservableLookup<K, V>
    {
        private IDisposable _subscription = null; 
        private readonly Dictionary<K, ReplaySubject<V>> _lookups = new Dictionary<K, ReplaySubject<V>>();

        internal ObservableLookup(IObservable<T> source, Func<T, K> keySelector, Func<T, V> valueSelector, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            _subscription = source.ObserveOn(scheduler).Subscribe(
                t => this.GetReplaySubject(keySelector(t)).OnNext(valueSelector(t)),
                ex => _lookups.Values.ForEach(rs => rs.OnError(ex)),
                () => _lookups.Values.ForEach(rs => rs.OnCompleted()));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_subscription != null)
            {
                _subscription.Dispose();
                _subscription = null;
                _lookups.Values.ForEach(rs => rs.Dispose());
                _lookups.Clear();
            }
        }

        private ReplaySubject<V> GetReplaySubject(K key)
        {
            if (!_lookups.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _lookups.Add(key, new ReplaySubject<V>());
            }
            return _lookups[key];
        }

        public IObservable<V> this[K key]
        {
            get
            {
                if (_subscription == null) throw new ObjectDisposedException("ObservableLookup");
                return this.GetReplaySubject(key).AsObservable();
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface IObservableLookup<K, V> : IDisposable
{
    IObservable<V> this[K key] { get; }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
IObservable<Packets> Packets = ...

IObservableLookup<int, Packets> lookup = Packets.ToLookup(p => p.Id, p => p, Scheduler.Default);

lookup[1].Subscribe(p => { });
lookup[2].Subscribe(p => { });
// etc
```

The nice thing with this is that you can subscribe to values by key **before** a value with that key has been produced by the source observable.

Don't forget to call `lookup.Dispose()` when done to clean up the resources.

Comment: _lookups.Values.ForEach method not found?

Comment: @DanUK86 - Sorry, I'm also using the Interactive Extensions - NuGet "System.Interactive".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy` to split the data. I would suggest you set up all subscriptions first and then activate your source. Doing so would result in one huge nested `GroupBy` query, but it is also possible to multi-cast your groups and subscribe to them individually. I wrote a small helper utility to do so below.

Because you still might want to add new routes after the source has been activated (done trough `Connect`), we use `Replay` to replay the groups. `Replay` is also a multi-cast operator so we wont need `Publish` to multi-cast.

```
public sealed class RouteData<TKey, TSource>
{
    private IConnectableObservable<IGroupedObservable<TKey, TSource>> myRoutes;

    public RouteData(IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        this.myRoutes = source.GroupBy(keySelector).Replay();
    }

    public IDisposable Connect()
    {
        return this.myRoutes.Connect();
    }

    public IObservable<TSource> Get(TKey id)
    {
        return myRoutes.FirstAsync(e => e.Key.Equals(id)).Merge();
    }
}

public static class myExtension
{
    public static RouteData<TKey, TSource> RouteData<TKey, TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return new RouteData<TKey, TSource>(source, keySelector);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public class myPackage
{
    public int Id;

    public myPackage(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}

class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var source = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3 }.ToObservable().Select(i => new myPackage(i));
        var routes = source.RouteData(e => e.Id);
        var subscription = new CompositeDisposable(
            routes.Get(5).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine),
            routes.Get(4).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine),
            routes.Get(3).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine),
            routes.Connect());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to consider writing a custom IObserver that does your bidding. I've included an example below.

```
void Main()
{
    var source = Observable.Range(1, 10);
    var switcher = new Switch<int, int>(i => i % 3);
    switcher[0] = Observer.Create<int>(val => Console.WriteLine($"{val} Divisible by three"));
    source.Subscribe(switcher);
}

class Switch<TKey,TValue> : IObserver<TValue>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, IObserver<TValue>> cases;
    private readonly Func<TValue,TKey> idExtractor;

    public IObserver<TValue> this[TKey decision]
    {
        get
        {
            return cases[decision];
        }
        set
        {
            cases[decision] = value;
        }
    }

    public Switch(Func<TValue,TKey> idExtractor)
    {
        this.cases = new Dictionary<TKey, IObserver<TValue>>();
        this.idExtractor = idExtractor;
    }

    public void OnNext(TValue next)
    {
        IObserver<TValue> nextCase;
        if (cases.TryGetValue(idExtractor(next), out nextCase))
        {
            nextCase.OnNext(next);
        }
    }

    public void OnError(Exception e)
    {
        foreach (var successor in cases.Values)
        {
            successor.OnError(e);
        }
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        foreach (var successor in cases.Values)
        {
            successor.OnCompleted();
        }
    }
}
```

You would obviously need to implement idExtractor to extract the ids from your packet.

Comment: I like this, going to try it out... at first glance looks good.

Comment: There's no benefit for doing so.  Why not just create observables that filter 1s, 2s, 3s, etc and subscribe to those?  Your code now suddenly becomes complex and difficult to maintain for I-don't-know-what-kind-of-performance-gain

Comment: If ever you find yourself implementing `IObserver<TValue>` (or `IObservable<TValue>`) then you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @DanUK86 - No, Dan, this is bad.